# Getting maximum value and name for column, and conditioning other columns on it in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of about ~15 columns. A_1 A_2 B_1 B_2 C_1 C_2... I am trying to compare column A and B, get the highest value in a column comparing A and B, and the name of the column with the highest value, then use that to grab values and names from the other columns. BUT, if A_1 and A_2 are equal I want it to compare B_1 and B_2 instead and pick the highest and based on that select values from C_1/C_2 D_1/D_2 and so on. So procedurally:

1. Get max value for A_1 vs. A_2
2. Get name of max column for A_1 vs. A_2
3. If A_2 is the max, then get the name and value for B_2, C_2 and so on
4. If A_1 = A_2, compare B_1 and B_2 instead and then get names and values for C_1/C_2 etc.

I've gotten to step 3 in the code, but can't seem to figure out how to jump to step 4 without this very ugly solution that gives the expected output. Replicate example below:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID    A_1   A_2    B_1   B_2
 11      1       2       3       4
 32      5       6       7       8
 73      15       12       10       11
 84      13       13       15       16
 65      2       1       2       5
                  ", header = TRUE)



j1 <- max.col(dat[c("A_1","A_2")], "first")
dat$max_A_name <- names(dat[c("A_1","A_2")])[j1]

k1 <- max.col(dat[c("B_1","B_2")], "first")
dat$max_B_name <- names(dat[c("B_1","B_2")])[k1]


dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(max_A_val=ifelse(max_A_name=="A_1",A_1,A_2)) %>%
  mutate(B_name=ifelse(max_A_name=="A_1","B_1","B_2")) %>% 
  mutate(B_val=ifelse(max_A_name=="A_1",B_1,B_2)) %>% 
  mutate(B_name=ifelse(A_1==A_2,max_B_name,B_name)) %>% 
  mutate(max_B_val=ifelse(max_B_name=="B_1",B_1,B_2)) %>% 
  mutate(B_val=ifelse(A_1==A_2,max_B_val,B_val))
dat
```

Comment: Tried to solve it, very ugly solution... but gives this expected output, I'll add it to the top

Answer (score 0):

I think using dplyr won't be suitable for this. Here's my version if I understand your question. I added a C_1 and C_2 column. Since A_1's max > A_2's max, then you should select B_1 and C_1 which is the output of the below code.

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID    A_1   A_2    B_1   B_2  C_1 C_2
 11      1       2       3       4  3 15
 32      5       6       7       8  5 1
 73      15       12       10       11  14  12
 84      13       13       15       16  12  21
 65      2       1       2       5  14  24
                  ", header = TRUE)

# order your non ID columns alphabetically
dat <- dat[,c(1, order(colnames(dat)[2: ncol(dat)]) + 1)]

# loop through each pair and assess max; if a max is found, break.
maxIndex <- NA
for (i in seq(2, ncol(dat), 2)) {
  colNameOne <- colnames(dat)[i]
  colNameTwo <- colnames(dat)[i + 1]
  
  colValuesOne <- dat[, i]
  colValuesTwo <- dat[, i + 1]
  
  if (max(colValuesOne) > max(colValuesTwo)) {
    maxIndex <- i
    break
    
  } else if (max(colValuesTwo) > max(colValuesOne)) {
    maxIndex <- i + 1
    break
  }
}

# if there was a max found, display the next columns.
if (!is.na(maxIndex)) {
  datInterested <- dat[, seq(maxIndex + 2, ncol(dat), 2)]
}

datInterested
```