# Maximum values for two columns, need to use loops?

Tags: r

I've been trying to use loops but they just aren't working, since I haven't done anything with this complexity before and I have been trying to solve this with dplyer, which has been an impossible exercise. I don't know what to do. Can anyone suggest any solutions?

- have columns A_1 A_2 B_1 B_2 C_1 C_2 D_1 D_2 E_1 E_2 F_1 F_2 G_1 G_2...
- 1000 rows each

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID    A_1   A_2    B_1   B_2    C_1   C_2    D_1   D_2    E_1   E_2    F_1   F_2    G_1   G_2
 11      1       2       3       4       3       4       3       4       3       4       3       4       3       4
 32      5       6       7       8       6       7       6       7       6       7       6       7       6       7
 73      15       15       10       10       3       4        3       4        3       4        3       4       2       2
 84      13       13       15       15       4       4        3       4        3       4        3       4       2       2
 65      2       2       2       2      2       2       2       2      2       2       2       1      2       2
                  ", header = TRUE)
```

- compare two columns A_1 and A_2
- take largest value (e.g. A_2)
- print the largest value in a third column (selected_A_2 val)
- print the largest name in a fourth column (selected_A_2 name)
- based on the fact that A_2 was the largest, take all values B_2, C_2, D_2, E_2... (assign new columns selected_B_2 name, selected_B_2 val, selected_C_2 name, selected_C_2 val)

The above was easy enough with dplyer conditioning. However, the below was impossible to do.

- However if A_1 == A_2, then compare B_1 and B_2
- take largest value (e.g. B_1)
- print the largest value in a third column (selected_B_1 val)
- print the largest name in a fourth column (selected_B_1 name)
- based on the fact that B_1 was the largest, take all values B_1, C_1, D_1, E_1... (assign new columns selected_C_1 name, selected_C_1 val, selected_D_1 name, selected_D_1 val)

And then

- However if A_1 == A_2 and B_1 == B_2 then compare C_1 and C_2
  and so on...
- if it happens that all are equal then just pick A_1 B_1 C_1... and move on

Any guidance would be appreciated!

EDIT: Expected output
[image: The yellow is the terminal comparison, the rest of the row whether column _1 or _2 is selected is based on the yellow item was _1 or _2]

**The yellow is the terminal comparison, the rest of the row whether column _1 or _2 is selected is based on the yellow item was _1 or _2**

Comment: Please show your expected output

Comment: Is this related to this question [getting-maximum-value-and-name-for-column-and-conditioning-other-columns-on-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69601065/getting-maximum-value-and-name-for-column-and-conditioning-other-columns-on-it)?

Comment: Hello... yes, but a different/extended version than that question.

Comment: sorry I'll put in the expected output!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `case_when()` in `tidyverse`? It allows for complex vectorized conditional statements. For example, although we do not have your expected output, this code structure could help you achieve some of your goals.

```
> dat <- dat %>% mutate(test = case_when(
+     A_1 == A_2 ~ case_when( #If A_1 and A_2 are the same, then check...
+         B_1 == B_2 ~ "wow",  #Whether B_1 and B_2 are the same and do "wow"
+         B_1 != B_2 ~ "cool"  #Whether they are different, and do "cool"
+     ),
+     A_1 != A_2 ~ "diff" #If the A's are not the same, define "diff"
+ ))
```

To understand what is going on here, the first `case_when()` is checking whether A_1 is the same as A_2 (for each row, it does it as a vector). If it is, then it moves to the next `case_when()` and checks whether B_1 is equal to B_2, or if they are different. You can see the output here. I defined a new column `test` based on these nested, vectorizable conditions, removing the need for for loops.

```
  ID A_1 A_2 B_1 B_2 C_1 C_2 D_1 D_2 E_1 E_2 F_1 F_2 G_1 G_2  test
1 11   1   2   3   4   3   4   3   4   3   4   3   4   3   4  diff
2 32   5   6   7   8   6   7   6   7   6   7   6   7   6   7  diff
3 73  15  15  10  10   3   4   3   4   3   4   3   4   2   2   wow
4 84  13  13  15  15   4   4   3   4   3   4   3   4   2   2   wow
5 65   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   wow
```

For your third and fourth bullet points under the things you wish to do but have struggled doing, you can easily do these nested structures with the `mutate()` function to define these new columns as you wish, as I have done.

That said, for the further iterations of C, D, and so on, you'll have to develop quite a nested conditionality here. There might be a more elegant way to solve this, but this approach should generally work. You could just further add more layers of `case_when()`. So, in my example code, starting at line 3, it might look like

```
B_1 == B_2 ~ case_when(
     C_1 == C_2 ~ case_when(
         ....
     ),
B_1 > B_2 ~ B_1, #New col's rows meeting this condition are assigned B_1
B_2 > B_1 ~ B_2 #These last two are my attempt to do your 3rd bullet point
```

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "largest name" though -- do your columns contain both character data and numerics that are currently held as characters?

Comment: By largest name I meant the name of the column where the largest value was chosen from (so if A_1=8, A_2=13) the largest value is 13, and the name of the column is A_2 (which I was thinking would then allow me to condition so that B_2, C_2 etc, are selected).

Comment: @mgtrek Hmm, I see. I think if you created sample output with at least A,B,C and D columns, I could come up with an exact solution.

Comment: Thank you, I created an output manually with A/B/C/D columns, let me know if anything doesn't make sense. Meanwhile reading about the use of case_when! (They all ended up being _2 by coincidence...)